# Ubuntu 14.10 display turns off on boot?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 14.10

I have Ubuntu 14.10 dual booting with Windows 8.1 on a Lenovo Y510P with a NVIDIA GT 755m graphics chipset.

I recently installed the proprietary NVIDIA driver version 340.65 on Ubuntu. After that I started getting "broken pipe" errors on the boot screen to Ubuntu.

Today while working on gedit, the screen froze and i had to reboot manually. but then instead of the usual user login screen, all I get is a dark screen and nothing else. Even the back light of the screen is off. Also, I know that the OS boots properly as I can hear the startup sound.

Any suggestions? Have a lot of data so... reluctant to re-install. :(

Answer (score 0):

This has happened a few times as well with flgrx graphics. I just boot into recovery (2nd Ubuntu in grub) then choose failsafe graphics. It makes some changes and then boots as normal. I've never actually ended up in failsafe, it just fixes problem and boots.

I usually see a message about fixing something to do with time offset.